# ScrollView on specific RelativeLayout

Tags: android, layout

I need your help on this design

[image]

As you can see the last item, which is a spinner doesn't fit on the Layout. The Layout in which are the textviews is a Relative Layout. And the gray background is a LinearLayout. So I want to be possible to scroll only the RelativeLayout (the one with white background) and not all the LinearLayout.
Is there a way to do that? Please I really would appreciate your answers.

Thank you

**MY CODE**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/gray">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewB"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="65dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:background="@drawable/registro_background"
            android:orientation="horizontal">



            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/ci"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_corner"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:hint="CI"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/orange"
                android:textColorHint="@color/naranja_lago"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/cliente_user"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/nombre"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/ci"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ci"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_corner"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/cliente_user"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:hint="Nombre y Apellido"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/orange"
                android:textColorHint="@color/naranja_lago"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/correo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/nombre"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_corner"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/orange"
                android:textColorHint="@color/naranja_lago"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/cliente_email"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/telefono"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/correo"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_corner"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:hint="Teléfono"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/orange"
                android:textColorHint="@color/naranja_lago"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/cliente_phone"/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/lugar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/telefono"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_corner"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:hint="Lugar"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="#6d6e71"
                android:textColorHint="#f7941e"
                android:textSize="20sp" />



        </RelativeLayout>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/registrar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_corner"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="REGISTRAR"/>




    </LinearLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/registro_cliente"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/viewB"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|center|center_horizontal" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: generally you should put the scrollview inside the relativelaout. please show us your code to better assist.

Comment: I already added my code, please help

Comment: did you try adding a `scrollView` just outside the `relativeLayout` so that the `relativeView` is a child of the `scrollView`?

Comment: I did, but didn't work. The scroll doesn't work on the relative layout. But if put the scroll outside of the LinearLayout the whole layout scroll, and that's not how i need it

Comment: pl check my answer if it helps you to find any clue

Answer (score 0):

I have tested a similar setup like you to test the scrolling of the views in the `RelativeLayout`, it works for me. Could you please check if it works for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="26dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_below="@id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="26dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_below="@id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="26dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_below="@id/button3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="26dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_below="@id/button4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="26dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```